# Beer Smith 2 Equipment settings.

Tags: equipment, brewing, software

Just got Beer Smith 2 and I was wondering if anyone has done equipment profiles and could give me some pointers on where to start.  Prost

Comment: There is an equipment wizard if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but here goes:
Look through the existing profiles to something that matches your setup the closest. Copy that profile and give it a new name.
I have a 3 tier system with a hot liquor tank, a drinks cooler with false bottom for mash tun and a stainless steel kettle.
First: get a large measuring jug and fill it to the top value. Pour this into your mashtun. (Keep count of how much you pour in). Repeat this step until you have the extraction hole (where the wort will pour from) covered. Now, tap out the water into your measuring jug until the water stops. Measure the difference - this is your mash tun dead space.
Next: Do exactly the same thing with your kettle.
Depending on your fermenter and method of beer extraction you can also use this technique there.
Next: Measure the weight of your kettle. Fill your kettle with water (30 liters is close enough to normal wort amounts for 18 liter batch) and start heating it up like you would on a normal brewday. When the water reaches a rolling boil you need to start your 60 minute timer. DO NOT CLOSE THE KETTLE! After 60 minutes switch the heat off and allow the water to cool to a safe temp. Measure the weight of the kettle with water. Subtract the kettle weight and then calculate the boil-off volume.
Mashtun temp loss is something that you can only really calculate when doing a mash, so make careful notes.
Remember to also test temp loss during transfer as that seems to be my biggest headache in hitting my mashtemp.